# How to switch off and restart android phone programmatically without root in marshmallow

Tags: android, architecture, operating-system, boot, bootloader

I want to make a app where user can set the time for switch off the phone and switch on (like user set the time for evening 7 pm to off and morning 7 am to switch on automatically). Is there any possible way to perform this action without rooted ?

Please suggest me.

And also try to give

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"/>
```

permission but it's also not possible for me to granted as manually and runtime.

Answer (score 4):

This permission is not available to third-party apps (see its [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT)).

Sorry, this is simply not something android will let you do – unless you root the device, of course.

Comment: is there any way run "adb reboot" command using the android app

Answer (score 0):

You cannot finish and restart the whole app. I suggest you to keep only one activity at time (good practices), and you can restart it just with:

```
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
```

This is an alternative because of the title of your question, but what you actually need is to create a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) or a [Broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) to achieve the functionality you need.

Tip: I recommend you to search alarm apps code examples.

Hope it helps you.